# Is it possible to add angular2 with nuget?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, angular

I'd like to add angular2 to a Visual Studio 2013 project, is it possible to do with nuget?

I found a [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1060262/First-Angular-App-with-TypeScript-and-Visual-Studi) describing I need Node Package Manager to do this, dated 30 Nov 2015.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible that a NuGet project exists that simply wraps up Angular2 into a package and while it is possible that you could add this to your solution, I would HIGHLY recommend that you avoid this course of action.

Microsoft has made a very deliberate decision to redirect efforts into supporting and expanding web standards.  Currently, the standard for Angular2 is to use npm to manage your scripts.  There is built-in gulp task runner support for this in VS 2015 and you can certainly manage it via gulp or grunt plugins in VS 2013.

Finally, consider how quickly the web world is moving right now.  Maintaining a NuGet package for every Angular2 version would be exhausting, if not disastrous.  Embrace the direction that the web is moving and switch to managing your JavaScript libraries with NPM, not NuGet.

Comment: I would mention that all npm packages are installed into node_modules, which is incompatible with the new ASP.NET 5 folder structure. Therefore npm is not all that smooth compared to NuGet yet, like Bower is.

Comment: That isn't true. You can easily add an npm configuration file to your project that ASP.Net 5 will pick up, installing node_modules within your dependencies special project section. See tutorials such as http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/283/asp-net-5-managing-client-side-dependencies-with-npm-bower-and-gulp. I'll continue to choose npm over Nuget for client-side libraries.

Comment: That works, however npm requires some gimmick (like gulp) to move the client-side dependencies. This is not required with bower or nuget. That being said, I also use npm (but use browserify instead).